# VMWare Workstation 11 on Windows 10 executes as 32bit and fails to start a Ubuntu Linux 64bit guest

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, bios, vmware-workstation

I recently upgraded to a 64bit Windows 10 based PC. I installed my older VMWare Workstation 11.1.2 on it and created a Ubuntu Linux 64bit 16.4 LTS. It appeared that the VM creation went through successfully. However, when I attempt to start the VM, I receive an error as below:
[image: VMWare error]

On inspecting the Task Manager, I observe that the VMWare Workstation is started as a 32bit process and could be the reason for this. Does this mean I can't run 64 bit guest OS on this PC?
[image: TaskManager]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says right there in the error message what the problem is, Intel VT-x is disabled. Have you checked your bios settings?

Comment: This setting was hidden under security for some reason and not under config>CPU. Enabled it and got it to work. Thanks.
Apparently the VMWare runs as a 32bit process is only for the GUI.